# How to enable streaming result set when using PostgreSQL JDBC and PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

By default, PostgreSQL JDBC reads all records into momery and then starts to process them.

If it is MySQL JDBC and MySQL database, I know how to do the reading and processing simultaneously. However, I don't know how to do it in PostgreSQL JDBC and PostgreSQL database.

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: How do you do it in MySQL JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

From [the link given](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor) by @a_horse_with_no_name, you should use JDBC cursors.

```
void streamSQL(Connection cnx, String sql) throws SQLException {
    cnx.setAutoCommit(false); // TODO: Remember autocommit status here
    try (Statement st = cnx.createStatement()) {
        st.setFetchSize(10); // TODO: Set buffer size here
        try (ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(sql)) {
            while (res.next()) {
                // TODO: Process row here, e.g. with a callback added as an argument to the method
            }
        }
    } finally {
        cnx.setAutoCommit(true); // TODO: Unless it was false earlier
    }
}
```

You can use it with queries that would return a huge result, e.g. `streamSQL(cnx, "SELECT * FROM big_table")` and it will feel like it's running smoothly (to the user).

Note, however, that if the *first 10 records* (10 being the "buffer size") returned by the query need many page scan, it will still take time. I don't know the implications on having a small buffer size, but this idiom is more efficient than the `LIMIT <n> OFFSET <k*n>` one in that there is only *one* query running, instead of one per page.